# select range of date's from a column with time stamp in python

Tags: python

I have a file with many columns along with few columns having 'dates'(say 20,27,53 are columns wth dates).
From a particular column(say 53), i want to select all the dates in a specific month(say may).
The problem is the format of date is "5/01/2011 12:53". I mean the date includes time also.

I tried few ways but the prompt points at the hour.

```
         >>> def daterange(start_date, end_date):
             ...     for n in range((end_date - start_date).days):
             ...         may_inav_writer.writerow()
             ... 
         >>> daterange(5/01/2011 00:00, 6/01/2011 00:00)
         File "<stdin>", line 1
         daterange(5/01/2011 00:00, 6/01/2011 00:00)
                              ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

this is the error i have got.

Guys...need your help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to call your daterange() function with arguments that look like dates without quotes or anything.  This is not how most programming languages work.  Try saying something like `datetime.strptime("5/01/2011 00:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`, in other words specifying the input format you expect to parse, and passing that to your function.

Comment: Pattern matching worked for me. thanks John and cat++

here is the python code:

import re

#after importing file and  a new file to write..,

for row in csvReader:
 try:
  if len(re.findall(r"5/[0-9]+/2011", row[52])):
   csvWriter.writerow(row)
  else:
   continue
 except:

Answer (score 0):

It's not a valid syntax whether it includes time or not (or rather, it's not doing what you think it's doing). You need to parse it into `datetime` object first.

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    date_format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'
    start_date  = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
    end_date    = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format)
    # ...

daterange('5/01/2011 00:00', '6/01/2011 00:00')
```